# supremum Proof by contradiction .

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

(The second part of the solution is confusing me)

**The Question:**

A is a bounded subset of ℝ

B = {b|b = 2a + 3, a ∈ A}

Prove that Sup(B) = 2Sup(A) + 3

**Part 1 of solution:**

We get 2a + 3 ≤ 2Sup(A) + 3

So B is bounded and
Sup(B) ≤ 2Sup(A) + 3

**Part 2 of solution**

We then want to show
Sup(B) ≥ 2Sup(A) + 3

As then we have equality:

The answer uses proof by contradiction and states that:

Assuming that Sup(B) ≥ 2Sup(A) + 3 is not true, then we have
Sup(B) < 2Sup(A) + 3

Therefore: we have Sup(A)₂ = [Sup(B)- 3]/2 which is an upper bound of A less than Sup(A)…a contradiction.

**My confusion**

What I don’t don’t understand is:
Yes Sup(A)₂ is less than Sup(A) but how do we know Sup(A)₂ is an upper bound of A?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following result: Let A and C sets, we define $A+C=\{a+c: a\in A, c\in C\}$, then $\sup(A+C)=\sup(A)+\sup(C)$. Now let $C=\{3\}$ and $B=A+C$

Comment: Thank you Lil, I've been over this a couple of times but it's not quite clear to me. Could you provide more detail?